# What is the “Allow Anonymous Inbound SIP Calls” option under “Asterisk SIP Settings” in FreePBX for?

Tags: asterisk, freepbx

I am looking for the canonical definition of the “Allow Anonymous Inbound SIP Calls” option under “Asterisk SIP Settings” in FreePBX. Also, how does it relate to "Allow SIP Guests"? 
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This option is to allow calls not associated with any of your trunks. Usually you want that disabled. To make it more clear, if this were a VoIP phone with this option on, the device would ring at random times since it would accept any "INVITE" mainly coming from sip scanners.